# Prolog compiler gives syntax error due to operator expression

Tags: prolog

Using Sicstus and given the list

```
[b > f, f > c, c > b, g > h, g > g, d, b, f > k, k > f, f > c]
```

I want to transform it to:

```
graph([b,c,d,f,g,h,k],[e(b,f),e(c,b),e(f,c),e(f,k),e(g,g),e(g,h),e(k,f)])
```

My goal is to transform the first list to the two separate lists by only   one pass through the former and the usage of two accumulators.

```
hf_to_graph_term([H|T], AccN, Nodes, AccE, Edges):-
    H = A>B,!,
    merge([H],AccE,NewAccE),
    hf_to_graph_term(T,AccN,Nodes,NewAccE,Edges).
```

However, I get the error message:

```
 ! Syntax error
 ! operator expected after expression
 ! in line 290
 ! hf_to_graph_term ( [ H | T ] , AccN , Nodes , AccE , Edges ) :- H = A 
 ! <<here>>
 ! > B , ! ,
```

This is because `>` is reserved as comparison operator.

Which changes do I have to make in my code?

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a priority clash: for the interpreter it is not clear how it should read `H = A > B`, as `H = (A > B)`, or `(H = A) > B`?

The solution is to make this explicit, and **use brackets**. You can rewrite the predicate to:

```
hf_to_graph_term([H|T], AccN, Nodes, AccE, Edges):-
    H = (A > B),
    !,
    merge([H],AccE,NewAccE),
    hf_to_graph_term(T,AccN,Nodes,NewAccE,Edges).
```

or you can do this in a more canonical form:

```
hf_to_graph_term([H|T], AccN, Nodes, AccE, Edges):-
    H = >(A, B),
    !,
    merge([H],AccE,NewAccE),
    hf_to_graph_term(T,AccN,Nodes,NewAccE,Edges).
```

Since here you do not seem to use `A` or `B`, we can also use underscores:

```
hf_to_graph_term([H|T], AccN, Nodes, AccE, Edges):-
    H = >(_, _),
    !,
    merge([H],AccE,NewAccE),
    hf_to_graph_term(T,AccN,Nodes,NewAccE,Edges).
```